# MYSQL INSERT fails on specific columns

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am positive this is fairly straight forward, however it is something I have not come across myself before and I am unable to find any information online.

I have a simple PHP based script which passes variables into a mysql_query command. The query is then executed, and the data is posted to a database.

The table columns type is VARCHAR, though I have experimented with both numbers and text with the same result.

To troubleshoot this, I printed the string passed to the mysql_query command to ensure the fault did not lie there. The string is valid, and when pasted into phpmyadmin SQL page, the INSERT is successful regardless of the data (numerical or text).

This is the exact string that is produced, and stored in a variable named `$query`:

```
INSERT INTO equipment VALUES ('IS3', 'Ice Screw', '', NULL, '747', '84', 'test', '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2016-03-09 17:00:56')
```

This string is then passed to `mysql_query($query)`.

So in summary, my INSERT fails to insert data to specific columns when the string is passed to the mysql_query command through PHP. No error is reported, and all other columns are inserted into. However the exact same string is completely valid and accepted when applied directly to the table via phpmyadmin SQL page.

Would anybody be able to point me in the right direction? It is difficult to word the problem in such a way that google or any other search tool returns relevant results- most results are for completel INSERT failures or column data types (trying to insert text into an INT etc).

Any help much appreciated.

I am also aware mysql commands have been deprecated.

```
$EquipmentID=$_POST['equipmentEquipmentID'];
$EquipmentType=$_POST['equipmentEquipmentType'];  
$EquipmentName=$_POST['equipmentEquipmentName'];
$Serial=$_POST['equipmentSerial'];
$Compliance=$_POST['equipmentCompliance'];
$Manufacturer=$_POST['equipmentManufacturer'];
$Date_In_Service=$_POST['equipmentDate_In_Service'];
$Date_Of_Purchase=$_POST['equipmentDate_Of_Purchase'];
$Date_Of_Manufacture=$_POST['equipmentDate_Of_Manufacture'];
if ($EquipmentType == 'Ice Screw') {;
    $Rating=$_POST['equipmentRating'];
    $Serial=$_POST['equipmentSerial'];
    $Size=$_POST['equipmentSize'];
    $add_equipment = "INSERT INTO equipment VALUES ('$EquipmentID', '$EquipmentType', '', "
    .($EquipmentName == NULL ? 'NULL, ' : "'$EquipmentName', ")."
    '$Rating', '$Size', '$Serial', '$Compliance', "
    .($Manufacturer == NULL ? 'NULL, ' : "'$Manufacturer', ").""
    .($Date_In_Service == NULL ? 'NULL, ' : "'$Date_In_Service', ").""
    .($Date_Of_Purchase == NULL ? 'NULL, ' : "'$Date_Of_Purchase', ").""
    .($Date_Of_Manufacture == NULL ? 'NULL, ' : "'$Date_Of_Manufacture', ")."
    '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";
    echo $add_equipment;
}
```

Comment: Table structure would be relevant.

Comment: It is a good practice to always specify columns list between table name and `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far- I have tried this with specifying the columns and there was no difference.

Comment: Any suggestions guys?

Comment: You might want to include the php code that is handling this query.

Comment: Added the PHP code that builds the query string, this is then passed to mysql_query($add_equipment)

Comment: You're sure your php code points to the same server that the phpmyadmin is running against?

Comment: It's all localhost, and the fact that the other columns are populated (EquipmentType for example) suggests the issue does not lie there.